# Setting up basic authentication in druid

Tags: pivot-table, olap, druid

I want to set up an authentication for Druid. I followed the example to set up druid from http://druid.io/docs/latest/tutorials/quickstart.html

Once done, I followed this document to setup authentication: http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/druid-basic-security.html

These are the following changes in common.runtime.properties file

```
# Basic authentication
# Basic authentication: Authenticator settings
druid.auth.authenticatorChain=["MyBasicAuthenticator"]
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.type=basic
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.initialAdminPassword=password1
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.initialInternalClientPassword=password2
druid.auth.authenticator.MyBasicAuthenticator.authorizerName=MyBasicAuthorizer


druid.auth.authorizers=["MyBasicAuthorizer"]
druid.auth.authorizer.MyBasicAuthorizer.type=basic
```

When I make a POST request to the url: http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/?pretty

with the body:

```
{
  "queryType" : "topN",
  "dataSource" : "wikiticker",
  "intervals" : ["2015-09-12/2015-09-13"],
  "granularity" : "all",
  "dimension" : "page",
  "metric" : "edits",
  "threshold" : 25,
  "aggregations" : [
    {
      "type" : "longSum",
      "name" : "edits",
      "fieldName" : "count"
    }
  ]
}
```

with username as: druid_system and password as: password2

I get the following error:

```
io.druid.java.util.common.IAE: No authenticator found with prefix: [MyBasicAuthenticator]
```

Does anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: Did you include the druid basic security extension

Comment: Yes Madhu, I added them as follows: druid.extensions.loadList=["druid-basic-security"]

Comment: Please post the code of MyBasicAuthenticator. I feel that your Json type annotations are not defined properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your config is missing an `escalator`.

Add the following:

```
# Escalator for the internal client that is used for the internal druid communication
druid.escalator.type=basic
druid.escalator.internalClientUsername=druid_system
druid.escalator.internalClientPassword=password2
druid.escalator.authorizerName=BasicAuthorizer
```